# Mail merge equivalent for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf, mail-merge

Is there an equivalent of Word mail merge in Excel?

I would like to generate PDF documents from an Excel template where each document has different input in two cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the table in Word, then use Excel as the data source and print the merged documents to PDF. That's the way mail merge works best. Excel does not have a mail merge functionality. You'd have to re-invent the wheel and it's likely much faster to do this with Word. Any calculation you may do in Excel can be included in the Excel data source and fed into the Word merge document.